# How can i solve this org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source
```

Comment: post the testng.xml file content

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have malformed `testng.xml`. There are either some content before `<?xml` or some not accepted content inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide some background as to  -- how you got this exception. And also did you validated the testNG XML to see if XML is properly formatted.
You can use Eclipse or any IDE of your choice to check and validate the xmls.

Please paste your XML and also share the entire error stack trace, to get the correct and quick resolution. 
From the exception it seems that it might be owing to some whitespaces in the XML.